# Conditional expectation Doubt

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $\{X_n\}$ be non-negative integrable random variables on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathscr{P})$ adpated to a filtration $\{ \mathscr{F_n}\}$ and bounded a.s. by a constant $C < \infty$. Let $\{ \mathscr{F_{-1}}\}=\{\phi, \Omega\}$. Show that the sets $\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n < \infty \}$ and $\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E[X_n |\mathscr{F_{n-1}]}  < \infty \}$ coincide a.s.

How to proceed here. Hint Enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is the following theorem (3.1 p.239 in Durrett's book *Probability: Theory and Examples*, second edition):

> Let $(S_j)_{j=1}^{+\infty}$ be a martingale, where $S_j=\sum_{k=0}^jX_k$ and $|X_k(\omega)|\leqslant M$ almost surely ($M$ is constant). Define 
>   $$C:=\{\omega,\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n(\omega)\mbox{ exists and is finite}\}
> $$
>   $$D:=\{\omega, \limsup_{n\to \infty}S_n(\omega)=+\infty,\liminf_{n\to \infty}S_n(\omega)=-\infty.$$
>   Then $\mathbb P(C\cup D)=1$.

The proof goes as follow: assume that $X_0=0$ and fix $K$ and define $N:=\inf\{n,X_n\leqslant -K\}$. Notice that $(S_{n\wedge N}+K+M)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a positive submartingale, hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n$ exists on $\{N=\infty\}$. Letting $K\to +\infty$, we can see that the limit exists provided that $\liminf_n S_n>-\infty$.

Comment: But, My martingale is the following $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i- E[X_i|\mathscr{F_{i-1}}])$. Even if I apply this theorem, I get $P(C\cup D) =1$ whereas I want a subset $C'$ (where both the series converge) of $C$ to have full probability i.e $P(C')=1$.

Comment: You can proceed by double inclusion: if $\omega$ is such that $\sum_i X_i$ converges and you are not in $C$, then you consider the case where $\omega\in D$. But in this case the $\limsup$ is finite because the $X_i$'s are non)negative.

Comment: Correct. $D$ can't happen here. But, why can't both $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E[X_n |\mathscr{F_{n-1}]} $ diverge ?

Comment: It can happen, for example if $X_n=1/n$ for each $n$. But if you call $C'$ the set where the first series converge, $C''$ that where the second series converges, then $C\Delta C'$ (symmetric difference) has zero measure.

Comment: yeah. I got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You are welcome.